# How to root my next book premium 8 tablet

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, nextbook-premium-8

How do I root my nextbook premium 8 tablet

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guidelines from xda forum
have a look at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1374742

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies.